# Creating dict from excel worksheet columns with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, recursion

I'm trying to parse through a directory of n .xslx files and create a .py file that's just a dict of the first two columns, but I'm running into the issue where with the code I have it only appends the first worksheets of the 2 workbooks in the directory. Here's the code I've written so far

```
import os
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
import pprint
import json

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

def get_did(xlsx, dbd):
    dbd = pd.read_excel(xlsx, index_col=0, usecols="A,B").to_dict()
    with open("db.py", 'a', newline='') as f:
        json.dump(dbd, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

path = os.getcwd()
filenames = os.listdir(path)

dbd = {}

for filename in filenames:
    if filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
        get_did(filename, dbd)

print(dbd)
```

the data I'm working with just has an ID number in the first column and a description string in the second so the output looks like this

```
{
    "Description": {
        "1": "45KV Suspension Polymer-DE",
        "2": "45KV Post Tie Polymer",
        "3": "45KV Post Vert SAC Polymer",
        "4": "45KV Post Hor SAC Polymer",
        "5": "35KV Post Tie",
        "6": "35KV Post Vertical SAC",
        "7": "45KV Post Vertical SAC",
        "8": "35KV Post Horizontal SAC",
                ...
        "72": "69KV Post Hor LAC Polymer",
        "73": "69KV Post Vert LAC Polymer",
        "74": "69KV Post Vert LAC Poly-Dbl",
        "75": "15KV Suspension Polymer",
        "76": "15KV Suspension Polymer-DE"
    }
}{
    "Size": {
        "1": "1/4\" EHS",
        "2": "5/16\" EHS",
        "3": "7/16\" EHS",
        "4": "9/16\" EHS",
        "5": "1/2\" AW",
        "6": "3#7 HS CW",
        "7": "7#8 HS CW",
        "8": "7#6 EHS CW",
        "9": "19#9 EHS CW",
        "10": "1/4\" GLV (3#7)"
    }
}
```

Ideally I'd like to have the string as the Key and the ID number as the Value, but the correct columns and information are being appended to the new file, just not all of the worksheets are included. I'm still new to pandas and recursion in general so I know there's a fundamental understanding of both that is the root issue, but any help getting to that understanding would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you want the output file to be excel or .py? and is it one file ?

Comment: Outputs as a .py file that's one dictionary from all of the worksheets

Answer (score 0):

basic idea is following, you can output in which ever format you prefer, but most common types are '.csv', '.txt' or excel:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path =os.chdir(r"yourdirectory")     
datalist=[]
mydict = {}

for file in os.listdir():
    filelist = [f for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith("xlsx")]

for fs in filelist:    
    df = pd.read_excel(fs, sep = '\t') 

    datalist.append(df)

alldata = pd.concat(datalist)
mydict = dict(zip(alldata[alldata.columns[0]], alldata[alldata.columns[1]]))

print(mydict)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Is it possible to have it create the dict from the column letter rather than the header titles for the columns? Worksheets all have different header names for the first 2 columns. My apologies, I should have made that clearer

Comment: when I run it I get this error "KeyError: '[0] not in index'", however if I print alldata everything seems to be in order... any advise?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: if it works for you please accept the answer and/or up vote, thanks